# Admin dashboard in wordpress 404 error

Tags: wordpress, admin, dashboard

I've tried everything on the web to fix this, but when I type `http://www.hotel-lopera.eu/wp-admin` it doesn't open.

I've tried updating it, making some changes in my cPanel and it still doesn't work...

Can you help me?

Comment: Can we have some more details? Apache/Nginx/etc configs maybe? Also some indication on what is happening on the logs could help point to the answer looks like a 301 redirect from curl Thanks //P

Answer (score 0):

Your admin url is http://www.hotel-lopera.eu/hotel-admin

it looks you may be using a plugin or htaccess redirect to redirect wp-admin to hotel-admin. But i am not sure what it could be.

I found this by guessing simply by typing http://www.hotel-lopera.eu/login/

and it redirected me to hotel-admin